# Google Maps API v3 - Dynamic Ad Size

Tags: javascript, google-maps, adsense

I am using the Google Maps API as described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference), and I added Adsense Ads to the page as defined [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/advertising). I would like to display different ad sizes based on the screen size of the device. Currently I display one size, that is too small for a desktop browser, and too large for a mobile browser.

Is there any way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking the javascript properties screen.width and screen.height.

Answer (score 1):

Place them in a container and set the container to be in % width and then set your iframe to be the same. So depending on the screen size your adds will expand to fix the percentage. You may need to fire a resize event to cater for a user minimizing the screen.  Example:

Your CSS:

```
.ad-holder{ width: 33%;height: 200px;} //width can be anything you declare
```

Your HTML:

```
<div class="ad-holder">
<iframe src="the map or ad" width="100%" height="200px" frameborder="0" id="map_options_styling_iframe">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you are referring to scaling the ads based on the screen size, but unfortunately that is against the rules of Google Adsense. I went with the answer above, because I ended up using javascript to check the screen size, and decide which ad size to display to the user.